# looking for a short film for a university project on sound design.

Tags: sound, design, foley, effects, film

I'm currently looking for a short film that I could use for a university project that requires me to create the sound design for a film of 3 - 8 minutes in length.

If anyone is willing to supply me with a film that I could use that would be fantastic or perhaps even point me in the direction of someone that you know or forums where I could maybe find one?

Regards,

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Go to the video part of stack exchange [video.stackexchange.com](http://video.stackexchange.com). Or try the Vimeo job/help wanted page. There's also mandy.com and craigslist (if you're in the states). You're looking for filmmakers, not fellow sound designers so its the wrong place to post your question.